# half-angle trig identity clarification

Tags: trigonometry

I am working on the following trig half angle problem. I seem to be on the the right track except that my book answer shows -1/2 and I didn't get that in my answer. Where did I go wrong?

$$\sin{15^{\circ}} = $$

$$\sin \frac { 30^{\circ} }{ 2 } = \pm \sqrt { \frac { 1 - \cos{30^{\circ}} }{ 2 } } $$

$$\sin \frac { 30^{\circ} }{ 2 } = \pm \sqrt { \frac { 1 - \frac {\sqrt 3 }{ 2 } }{ 2 } } $$

$$\sin \frac { 30^{\circ} }{ 2 } = \pm \sqrt { \frac { 1 - \frac {\sqrt 3 }{ 2 } }{ 2 } (\frac {2} {2}) } $$

$$\sin \frac { 30^{\circ} }{ 2 } = \pm \sqrt { 2 - \sqrt {3} } $$

Book Answer
$$\sin \frac { 30^{\circ} }{ 2 } =  -\frac {1} {2}  \sqrt { 2 - \sqrt {3} } $$

Comment: As $\sin{30^{\circ}} = 1/2$, I do not know how $\sin{15^{\circ}}$ is to equal $-1/2$.  You have the right idea.

Comment: You're close! When you multiplied by $(2/2)$, you should have gotten a denominator of $4$, which can be pulled out of the radical as a multiplied $1/2$. Since $15^\circ$ is in the first quadrant, the sign of the sine should be positive, so the "book answer" is wrong in that regard.

Comment: @Blue thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the $4^{th}$ equation, you should have $$\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{2}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}}=\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}.$$ Since $30/2$ is in the first quadrant, the answer should be the positive.

Comment: thanks for the example and clarification

Comment: @sam: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt { \dfrac { 1 - \dfrac {\sqrt 3 }{ 2 } }{ 2 } \times \dfrac22} = \sqrt{\dfrac{2-\sqrt3}{\color{red}4}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}{\color{red}2}$$